# MSSQL Bulk Insert for multiple tables avoid repetition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my SQL statement for BULK insertion of two tables from .txt file:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ImportNutritionDataToDatabase;

USE [AppTest];

-------------------------------------------------------
-- Food Group Descriptions #1
-------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(1000) = 'D:\CodePurehope\App\Dev\NutrientData\FD_GROUP.txt';

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
 (
    [FoodGroupCode] VARCHAR(666) NOT NULL, 
    [FoodGroupDescription] VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
 )

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT #TempTable FROM ''' + @Path + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =''^'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC(@sql);

UPDATE #TempTable
   SET [FoodGroupCode] = REPLACE([FoodGroupCode], '~', ''),
       [FoodGroupDescription] = REPLACE([FoodGroupDescription], '~', '')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FoodGroupDescriptions]
(
    [FoodGroupCode],
    [FoodGroupDescription]
)
SELECT
    [FoodGroupCode],
    [FoodGroupDescription]
FROM
    #TempTable
GO

DROP TABLE #TempTable

-------------------------------------------------------
-- Food Description #2
-------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(1000) = 'D:\CodePurehope\App\Dev\NutrientData\FOOD_DES.txt';

CREATE TABLE #TempTable2
 (
    [NutrientDatabankNumber] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FoodGroupCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [LongDescription] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [ShortDescription] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [CommonName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ManufacturerName] [varchar](165) NULL,
    [Survey] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ReferenceDescription] [varchar](235) NULL,
    [RefusePercentage] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ScientificName] [varchar](65) NULL,
    [NitrogenFactor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ProteinFactor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [FatFactor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [CarbohydratesFactor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
 )

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT #TempTable2 FROM ''' + @Path + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =''^'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC(@sql);

UPDATE #TempTable2
   SET [NutrientDatabankNumber] = REPLACE([NutrientDatabankNumber], '~', ''),
       [FoodGroupCode] = REPLACE([FoodGroupCode], '~', ''),
       [LongDescription] = REPLACE([LongDescription], '~', ''),
       [ShortDescription] = REPLACE([ShortDescription], '~', ''),
       [CommonName] = REPLACE([CommonName], '~', ''),
       [ManufacturerName] = REPLACE([ManufacturerName], '~', ''),
       [Survey] = REPLACE([Survey], '~', ''),
       [ReferenceDescription] = REPLACE([ReferenceDescription], '~', ''),
       [RefusePercentage] = REPLACE([RefusePercentage], '~', ''),
       [ScientificName] = REPLACE([ScientificName], '~', ''),
       [NitrogenFactor] = REPLACE([NitrogenFactor], '~', ''),
       [ProteinFactor] = REPLACE([ProteinFactor], '~', ''),
       [FatFactor] = REPLACE([FatFactor], '~', ''),
       [CarbohydratesFactor] = REPLACE([CarbohydratesFactor], '~', '')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FoodDescriptions]
(
    [NutrientDatabankNumber],
    [FoodGroupCode],
    [LongDescription],
    [ShortDescription],
    [CommonName],
    [ManufacturerName],
    [Survey],
    [ReferenceDescription],
    [RefusePercentage],
    [ScientificName],
    [NitrogenFactor],
    [ProteinFactor],
    [FatFactor],
    [CarbohydratesFactor]
)
SELECT
    [NutrientDatabankNumber],
    [FoodGroupCode],
    [LongDescription],
    [ShortDescription],
    [CommonName],
    [ManufacturerName],
    [Survey],
    [ReferenceDescription],
    [RefusePercentage],
    [ScientificName],
    [NitrogenFactor],
    [ProteinFactor],
    [FatFactor],
    [CarbohydratesFactor]
FROM
    #TempTable2
GO

DROP TABLE #TempTable2


COMMIT TRANSACTION ImportNutritionDataToDatabase;
GO
```

How could I simplify this without repetitions of paths, using one temptable etc?

Comment: Since the files are of different structures, and of different final tables I don't see why you would really want to.

Comment: What about declaration of global path, so I can change it only in one place if path is different?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the thing that SSIS is meant for. I would suggest using that for your ETL from files. It will allow much greater efficiency in the development process and can be configured to handle invalid data elements much easier. Changing the paths is also much easier since you can override them in SQL agent jobs in each environment.